# `this` scope changes on import

Tags: javascript, node.js, node-modules

I have such a situation in my NodeJS project:

```js
//utility.js

module.exports = () => {
   console.log(this.property1);
}
```

```js
//main.js
const utilityFunc = require(./utility);

class MyClass {

  constructor(name){
    this.property1 = name; 
  }

  foo(){
    //...
    utilityFunc();
  }

}

const myObject = new MyClass('A name');
myObject.foo();
```

What I expect is to output 'A name', but `property1` is not defined in the scope of `this`. This code seems to work if I write the function in `main.js` instead of importing it. I'm trying to figure out why this happens.

Comment: `This code seems to work if I write the function in main.js instead of importing it.` I doubt it does.

Comment: You are very significantly misunderstanding how `this` works. The value of `this` in your utility module will be the module context in which the function was declared.